# function returning space

Tags: whitespace, insert-char

I would like to have a function that gives me spaces according to a number `i` multiplied by a factor `f`.  So I end up with returning 6 spaces with `(spaces 3 2)`.

This is to be able to indent some debugging comments in my elisp code when there are splits in the code (e.g. conditionals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-u 8 SPC` will insert 8 spaces.

Equivalently from lisp:

```el
(self-insert-command 8 ?\s)
```

Comment: An elisp function is what I need.